# Push Notifications on Android using FCM and AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to send push notifications to android app using FCM and AWS. In most of the cases, the notifications are received on device's end, but for few devices, the AWS throws a delivery error 'Not Registered'.

The FirebaseMessagingService returns the same device token and even Firebase Cloud Messaging does not throw any error. Any insights of how to get notifications all the time using AWS and FCM ?

Comment: We'll need quite a bit more detail to provide useful feedback. What AWS service are you using to send notifications (Pinpoint? SNS?). How are you registering the devices, with what client-side code?